# What is the best 3D modelling software for my purpose?

Tags: 3d, 3d-modelling, 3d-model

I am working on a presentation, I think of adding a model of a hydroponic system, there should be some pipes which are parallel, connected with small pipes, the large ones should have holes and plants getting out of them. I never made a 3D model, which program can I learn to use in less than a week?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not looking for a pretty solution  you could just use sketchup. You can also use blender for the images but blender is not as easy to use and sketchup has a tendency to silently mess up 3D model's meshes. In other words: you can use sketchup, there are premade templates for plants as well but don't expect too much. Making good-looking plants is tough, even for experienced users.

Your best bet is probably to look for a preexisting model and maybe edit it a bit.

Conclusion: 3D-editing is hard, especially when it comes to features such as plants and in a week you can achieve some things, but no good looking renders like the ones on YT.
Sorry :/
You could consider looking into it further for future projects.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you think I can at least be able to design these pipes or holes?